# How to auto increment duplicate values by a specific number in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-2.7, math

I am expecting the list to be sorted and then duplicates will be spaced by increments of 0.1. Why is my code below not working? Here is what I am expecting to get versus what my program is returning:

> **Expected Output**: `[11, 15, 15.1, 20, 20.1, 20.2, 20.3, 20.4, 30,
>   30.1, 40, 40.1, 50, 50.1]`
>
> **Actual output**:`[11, 15, 15.1, 20, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 30, 30.1, 40,
>   40.1, 50, 50.1]`

## Python Code:

```
my_list = [20,20,20,30,20,30,40,50,15,11,20,40,50,15]
my_list.sort()
dup_list = []


for i in range (len(my_list)):
    if my_list[i] not in dup_list:
        dup_list.append(my_list[i])
    else:
        my_list[i] = my_list[i] + 0.10

    dup_list.append(my_list[i])
```

Comment: What should happen if there are more than 10 duplicates for a given number ?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it ? The problem is you do not track how many times a number is duplicated. For example every time you read 20, your code don't know if it's the second time or the fourth, so it only add 0.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution according to your code.
your code is right what you were lacking was the case when `my_list[i]+0.1*i`
value is already present. ie in example when 20 is there you increase it to 
20.1 (happening) but you miss that but when 20.1 is there . you just checking
only for 20 not for 20.1 . that is why 20.1 is coming in your solution not 20.2.

```
my_list = [20,20,20,30,20,30,40,50,15,11,20,40,50,15]
my_list.sort()
dup_list = []


for i in range (len(my_list)):
    if my_list[i] not in dup_list:
        dup_list.append(my_list[i])
    else:
        j=1
        res = True
        while res:
            val = my_list[i]+j*0.1
            if val  not in dup_list:
                dup_list.append(val)
                res = False
            j+=1 

print(dup_list)

#output [11, 15, 15.1, 20, 20.1, 20.2, 20.3, 20.4, 30, 30.1, 40, 40.1, 50, 50.1]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group equal consecutive elements:

```
from itertools import groupby

my_list = [20,20,20,30,20,30,40,50,15,11,20,40,50,15]
my_list.sort()
result = [g + i * 0.1 for k, group in groupby(my_list) for i, g in enumerate(group)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[11.0, 15.0, 15.1, 20.0, 20.1, 20.2, 20.3, 20.4, 30.0, 30.1, 40.0, 40.1, 50.0, 50.1]
```

Answer (score 2):

I can propose simple fix to the original code:

```
my_list = [20,20,20,30,20,30,40,50,15,11,20,40,50,15]
my_list.sort()
dup_list = []

for i in range (len(my_list)):
    if my_list[i] not in dup_list:
        dup_list.append(my_list[i])
    else:
        dup_list.append(dup_list[i-1]+0.1)
```

Comment: Your solution leads to small inaccuracies because you're adding `0.1` multiple times instead of adding `0.X` (where X is the number of occurances) once. Try `20 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1` and `20 + 0.1 * 3` in the interpreter to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are only incrementing it once. You are not keeping a count of how many times a number has appeared before.

What you need is some kind of frequency dictionary that will store how many times this number has appeared. Using that frequency `f` you add `f-1` increments to the number.

```
my_list = [20,20,20,30,20,30,40,50,15,11,20,40,50,15]
my_list.sort()
dup_list = []
feq = {}

for i in range (len(my_list)):
    if my_list[i] not in feq:
        feq[my_list[i]] = 1
    else:
        feq[my_list[i]] += 1

    dup_list.append(my_list[i] + (feq[my_list[i]]-1)*0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this improved code:

```
my_list = [20,20,20,30,20,30,40,50,15,11,20,40,50,15]
my_list.sort()
out_list = []

for value in my_list:
    if value in out_list:
        while value in out_list:
            value += .1
    out_list.append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [20,20,20,30,20,30,40,50,15,11,20,40,50,15]
my_list.sort()
dup_list = []
occurrences = defaultdict(int)

for elmt in my_list:
    dup_list.append(elmt + occurrences[elmt] * 0.10)
    occurrences[elmt] += 1
```

Output:

```
[11.0, 15.0, 15.1, 20.0, 20.1, 20.2, 20.3, 20.4, 30.0, 30.1, 40.0, 40.1, 50.0, 50.1]
```

If you need the original values to still be integers, comment below and I'll change that.

Answer (score 0):

Another (more advanced) option is to write a cusom generator:

```
from itertools import count

def gen(value):
    """Returns a generator that first yields `value` and then `value + x * 0.10` (where x is 1, 2, ...).
    """
    yield value
    yield from map(lambda x: value + x * 0.10, count(1))

my_list = [20, 20, 20, 30, 20, 30, 40, 50, 15, 11, 20, 40, 50, 15]

# create a generator for each distinct value in my_list
generators = {k: gen(k) for k in set(my_list)}

# calculate the result list
dup_list = [next(generators[elmt]) for elmt in sorted(my_list)]

print(dup_list)
```

IMO, this is not the easiest solution. I'm sharing it anyways because it might help others understand generators, especially `yield from`.